# How can I connect DBeaver to an oracle database running into a Windows Server 2016 Hyper-V virtual machine?

Tags: networking, hyper-v, windows-server-2016, oracle-database, dbeaver

I don't even know how to diagnose this problem. I've deactivated the firewall of the Windows Server 2016, I am connecting it to internet by an external virtual switch of Hyper-V. I can ping it externally and receive response normally. But DBeaver just doesn't connect to it. The error I get is

> IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection   The
> Network Adapter could not establish the connection   The Network
> Adapter could not establish the connection
> Connection timed out: connect, socket connect lapse 21045 ms. /192.168.0.64 1521 0 1 true
> Connection timed out: connect, socket connect lapse 21045 ms. /192.168.0.64 1521 0 1 true
> Connection timed out: connect
> Connection timed out: connect

It's a typical timed out error. I can connect normally using DBeaver from inside the VM, but I don't get it from the outside. As I said, pings to the VM's ip (192.168.0.64) from outer machines receives responses as expected, but DBeaver still doesn't connects to it.

I need to connect DBeaver from the real machine to the database running into the virtual machine. Please help me.